# Лишний пользователь в SDDM

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde

После обновления на экране входа появился еще один польователь - Dynamic User. Зайти через него не получается, так же никаких записей об этом пользователе нет в passwd. Что это, откуда оно взялось и что с этим делать - не понятно. Система archlinux, граф. окружение - KDE Plasma

[image: Окно логина]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf
```

В секцию Users добавить строку/строки

```
HideUsers=systemd-timesync
HideShells=/bin/false /usr/bin/nologin /sbin/nologin
```

Answer (score 0):

Arch ставили сами? Динамический пользователь мог появится, если вы использовали сторонние способы установки ядра.
Пробовали просто удалить его?

```
userdel name
```

Comment: Ставил сам, просто удалить не выходит - нет видит его userdel

Answer (score -1):

```
nano systemd-timesyncd.service
DynamicUser=no
```

Comment: Прописывание DynamicUser=no в конфиг /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
не помогает, создание файла в домашней директории - тоже. Помогает отключение NTP, но как вариант решения вообще не очень.